# sqlplus obtener un archivo TXT para importar mediante spool

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle-11g, sqlplus

estoy trabajando con Oracle Database y necesito crear un script que me genere un archivo de importación en formato TXT. Estoy usando sqlplus y el comando spool para grabar las consultas pero por más que intento no logro acomodar los datos:

Lo que necesito es:

```
1|Retratos de gente|2|DC|4|4
2|Campanas|2|AC|7|5
3|Edificios historicos|2|DC|7|6
```

Pero lo que obtengo es:

```
        1|Retratos de gente   |              2|DC
                    4|                   4
        2|Campanas            |              2|AC
                    7|                   5
        3|Edificios historicos|              2|DC
                    7|                   6|T
```

¿Hay alguna forma de re-ordenar los datos?

Comment: y si colocas tu query? y la estructura de las tablas? y algunos datos de ejemplos para poder reproducir tu pregunta, saludos y bienvenido al sitio :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo resolví, la solución fue separar con dos barras verticales cada columna de la tabla seguida con el separador entre comillas:

```
SQL> select ID_CAS||'|'||DESC_CAS||'|'||ID_TIPO||'|'||ID_TIP||'|'||CANTIDAD||'|'||DIAS FROM CSM.CASUISTICAS;
```